# Fugen-en nach Nomen, die den Genitiv mit [e]s und den Plural mit e bilden

Tags: noun, compound

Laut [Komposition: Fugenelement en](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Komposition/WB-Elements/Fuge-en.html) stehe die Fuge "en" nach ***einigen*** Nomen, die den Genitiv mit *[e]s* und Plural mit *e* bilden:

- Greisenalter
- Storchennest
- straußenähnlich

Das o.g. Wort ***einigen*** schließt eine praktische Anwendung aus; die zitierte Regel ist nicht zufriedenstellend. Lässt sich die obige Gesetzmäßigkeit also für den praktischen Gebrauch weiter verfeinern? Wenn ja, wie?

Ich möchte also weitere Regeln bzw. Gesetzmäßigkeiten sehen, die die obige Klasse der Nomenkomposita der Form

**Nomen1 [+ evtl. Fuge] + Nomen2, so dass Nomen1 den Genitiv mit *[e]s* und den Plural mit *e* bildet**,

in drei Unterklassen aufteilen:

1. die Wörter der o.g. Klasse mit Fugen-[e]n, die einer Gesetzmäßigkeit folgen,
2. die Wörter der o.g. Klasse ohne Fugen-[e]n (also ganz ohne Fuge oder mit einer anderen Fuge), die einer Gesetzmäßigkeit folgen,
3. die restlichen Wörter der o.g. Klasse, bei denen sich keine festen Regeln formulieren lassen.

Dabei sollen die Klassen 1 und 2 möglich groß sein und zugleich einfach anwendbare Gesetzmäßigkeiten aufweisen.

Answer (score 3):

Vermutlich ist diese Antwort rein auf die deutsche Gegenwartssprache bezogen nicht ganz zufriedenstellend und beim Erlernen der deutschen Sprache auch nicht immer hilfreich, aber was die von Dir genannten Fälle (und andere) betrifft, so kann man folgende Regel aufstellen:

Substantive, die ursprünglich zur schwachen Deklination gehörten, haben als Fugenelement *-en*. Schwache Deklination heißt, dass sie in mittelhochdeutscher (mhd.) und zum teil frühneuhochdeutscher (fnhd.) Zeit ihren Genitiv Singular und ihren Nominativ Plural (eigentlich alle Fälle außen Nom. Sg.) auf *-en* bildeten. Zum Beispiel:

- nhd. *Greis* = mhd. *grîse* Gen. Sg.: *des grîsen* Nom. Pl. *die
  grîsen*
- nhd. *Storch* = mhd. *storche* (neben *storck*) Gen. Sg.: *des storchen* Nom. Pl. 
  *die storchen*
- nhd. *Strauß* = mhd. *strûze/strouze* (neben *struz*) Gen. Sg.: *des strûzen* Nom. Pl. *die strûzen*

Weitere Beispiele wären:

- nhd. *Hahn* (bspw. in *Hahnenschrei*) = mhd. *hane* Gen. Sg.: *des hanen* Nom. Pl.: *die hanen*
- nhd. *Schwan* (bspw. in *Schwanenhals*) = mhd. *swane* (neben *swan*) Gen. Sg.: *des swanen* Nom. Pl.: *die swanen*

Um die Regel zu wiederholen: Gehört das Wort ursprünglich zur schwachen Deklination, d.h. der Nom. Sg. ging im Mittelhochdeutschen auf *-e*, der Gen. Sg. auf *-en* und der Nom. Pl. auf *-en*, dann ist das Fugenelement *-en-* zu setzen.

Rein auf die deutsche Gegenwartssprache bezogen lässt sich hier, soweit ich die Literatur dazu überschaue, keine Regel aufstellen.

Comment: Deine Regel sagt leider nichts darüber aus, welcher Fugenlaut bei Wörtern zu verwenden ist, die mhd. nicht schwach dekliniert wurden, oder die gar keine Nomen sind (*nötig**en**falls*). Und wie ist zu erklären, dass es Eigennamen gibt, bei denen kein *»en«* die Fuge bildet (*Greisberger, Hahndorf, Hahnwald, Schwangau, Schwanthaler*) Und was ist mit dem *Hahnrei*? Und wie kann es sein, dass es sowohl eine *Modeschau* als auch eine *Modenschau* gibt?

Comment: @Hubert: Vielen Dank für Deinen Kommentar! In der Tat bezieht sich meine Antwort nur auf Substantive, um die es, so dachte ich zumindest, in der Frage geht. Was *nötigenfalls* betrifft, so handelt es sich hierbei nicht um ein Kompositum, wie bei den hier gefragten Fällen, sondern um eine sogenannte Zusammenrückung, bei der aus der Mehrworteinheit mit dem (flektierten) Adjektiv *nötigen* und dem (erstarrten) Genitiv von *Fall*, also *Falls*. Ähnliche Konstruktionen finden sich bspw. in *andernfalls*, *jedenfalls* oder *schlimmstenfalls*.

Comment: @ Hubert: Und zu *Hahnrei*: Die Herkunft dieses Wortes, vor allem des zweiten Elements, ist dunkel und sprengt den Rahmen dieser Kommentare hier. Hierbei handelt es sich aber jedenfalls um kein ursprünglich hochdeutsches, sondern um ein niederdeutsches Wort (*hanerei*), das wohl vor allem durch Luther in den hochdeutschen Sprachraum gekommen ist. Hier sind hinsichtlich der Bildung also noch andere Aspekte zu berücksichtigen.

Comment: @Hubert: Schließlich zu den Ortsnamen: Ja, bei den von Dir genannten (und zahlreichen anderen) Ortsnamen scheint das Fugenelement zu fehlen. Die Bildung von Eigennamen geht im Gegensatz vom "allgemeinen" Wortschatz allerdings häufig eigene Wege. Aber was Ortsnamen angeht, kenne ich mich nicht besonders gut aus.

Comment: @Hubert: Zu *Mode(n)schau*: Ja, hier findet man beides, obwohl die Form *Modenschau* wohl die gängigere ist. Bei *Mode* handelt es sich um ein Wort, das erst im Laufe des 17. Jhs. in den deutschen Wortschatz aufgenommen wurde. Hier greift die Regel nicht (mehr), da sich das System der deutschen Substantivflexion zu dieser Zeit bereits weiterverändert hat und *Mode* nicht mehr sinnvoll in ein "schwaches" Flexionsparadigma integriert werden konnte.

Comment: Interessante Frage! Soweit ich das sehe, finden sich im Deutschen (zumindest im Standarddeutschen) keine Bildungen mit einem *-at*-Wort als Erstglied. Das einzige, das ich finden konnte und das vielleicht allgemeiner bekannt ist, ist die *Prädikatenlogik*, wobei das *-en-* hier vermutlich kein Fugenelement darstellt, sondern eine Flexionsendung für den Dat. Pl. *Prädikaten*, also im Sinne von *Teilgebiet der Logik, das mit Prädikaten und deren Aussagen arbeitet* o.ä. (also handelt es sich auch nicht um ein *echtes* Kompositum).

Comment: Warum ich jetzt aber keine Bildungen mit *-at*-Wörtern als Erstglied finden konnte, wurmt mich gerade. Hast Du denn Beispiele?

Comment: @Bernhard Laminatboden, Salatschüssel, Granatapfel (ist das ein Kompositum?), Piratenschiff

Answer (score 0):

Tja, das ist einerseits das 'Defizit' aller Grammatiken, dass sie niemals alle Elemente nennen, die es gibt, geben kann oder geben könnte - du merkst schon. Dass du mit dem, was unter [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Komposition/WB-Elements/Fuge-en.html) steht, unzufrieden bist, leuchtet mir ein. Eisenberg schreibt in *Das Wort. Grundriss ...* (2013) hierzu u.a.: "Man kann nicht hoffen, die Vielfalt der Erscheinungen auch nur halbwegs vollständig zu erfassen." (226). Um dann Ausführungen über Fugen zu machen, die bis S. 231 gehen. :-) Lies ihn und entscheide selber, inwieweit das deinen Erwartungen entspricht.

Comment: Deine Art zu zitieren irritiert. Ich dachte erst, *Eisenberg* sei ein Beispiel, dazu noch ein falsches.