# Nomen + (s) + Suffix

Tags: suffix

Wenn man Adjektive aus Nomen und Suffixe wie *-los*, *-leer*, *-reich*, *-wert* usw. bildet, wann soll eine *s* zwischen das Nomen und Suffix eingesetzt werden?  Zum Beispiel, warum *zwanglos* aber *zwang**s**läufig*?  (Weitere Beispiele können sich am Ende [dieser Seite](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Suffixes.html) finden.)

Ich kann nicht festlegen, ob das eine grammatische oder fonetische Regel ist (oder etwas ganz anderes).

Comment: Ich würde behaupten, dass es da keine eindeutige Regel gibt; sich das eher "entwickelt" und vom Sprachempfinden der Nutzer:Innen abhängig ist. "Behindert mich das Fugen-S oder "brauche" ich es für eine angenehme Aussprache?"

Comment: Das Fugen-s wurde schon öfter hier behandelt. U.a. in https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43567/fugen-s-in-gefechtsst%c3%a4rke https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58023/beispielnummer-oder-beispielsnummer https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50200/fugen-en-nach-nomen-die-den-genitiv-mit-es-und-den-plural-mit-e-bilden

Comment: Die Regel lautet, dass es keine Regel gibt.

Comment: @mtwde Bis heute wusste ich wirklich nicht, dass es schon eine Bezeichnung für das Konzept gibt.  Ich hatte niemals ein Problem bei das "Fugen-s" mit Komposita; nur mit Adjektiven und Sufixen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das sogenannte "[Fugen-s](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut)" ist ein Phänomen, bei dem ein Sprecher zur Vereinfachung der Aussprache einen Fugenlaut zwischen die Elemente eines Kompositums einsetzt.Es ist besonders schwierig für Nichtmuttersprachler, zu entscheiden, wo denn ein Fugen-s angebracht sein könnte und wo nicht, zumal sich nichteinmal Muttersprachler darüber einig werden können (siehe "Schnellzugwagen" in "deutschem Deutsch" und "Schnellzugswagen" in schweizerischem Hochdeutsch).

Die einzige Regel, die mir spontan dazu einfällt, ist dass bei Komposita, die aus Adjektiv und Substantiv bestehen, ein Fugenlaut i.A. nur dann verwendet werden kann, wenn das Adjektiv *nach* dem Substantiv steht. Ansonsten ist das leider "nach Gefühl" bzw. "nach gängiger Praxis".

Comment: *Nur dann*, aber nicht *genau nur dann* (zum Gegenbeispiel *kugelrund*), falls ich die Antwort verstehe.

Comment: @c.p. Genau so. Nur dann überhaupt. Nicht immer dann.